# Elements only appear after using inspect element

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am previewing the attachments in another tab but contents only appear when I use inspect element.

NOTE: I am parsing data URL: as "cpmFile"

my code is

```
showAttachment(e, assetId) {
    var _this = this;
    axios.get(properties.baseUrl + "asset/id/" + assetId + "?apikey=" + properties.apiKey).then(function (response) {
      if (response.status == 200) {
       let cpmFile= 'data:'+response.data.data.mimetype+';base64,'+response.data.data.data;
        let win = window.open();
        win.document.write('<iframe src="' + cpmFile  + '" frameborder="0" style="display:block; border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
      }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      _this.setState({
        ActiveErrorMessage: true
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: You need to do `win.document.close()` after the write, to tell the browser to finish render

Comment: didn't work, also its not working in IE.

Comment: You still need to do it. What does "didn't work" mean? Errors in console?

Comment: I still got nothing on browser window of IE and there are no errors in console.

Comment: thanks for your time, I have already seen them, none of them is helpful.

Comment: I believe most of the links in the google search mentions a lack of support of the data-uri in IE